# How to treat files as huge string with macos grep?

Tags: macos, grep

I'm using the following command on Ubuntu to list all files containing a given pattern:

```
for f in *; do if grep -zoPq "foo\nbar" $f; then echo $f; fi; done
```

But on macos, I'm geting the following error:

```
grep: invalid option -- z
```

There's no `-z` option to treat files as a big string with macos grep, unlike gnu grep.

Is there another option on macos `grep` equivalent to `-z ? If not, what alternative can I use to get the same result ?

Comment: Install `pcregrep` and use it with `-M` flag.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Indeed, `pcregrep -Mq` works like a charm, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install `pcregrep` via `home brew`, and then use it with the [`-M` option](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/pcregrep.1.html):

> By default, each line that matches a pattern is copied to the
> standard output, and if there is more than one file, the file name is
> output at the start of each line, followed by a colon. However, there
> are options that can change how pcregrep behaves. In particular, the
> **-M** option makes it possible to search for patterns that span line
> boundaries. What defines a line boundary is controlled by the **-N**
> (**--newline**) option.

Answer (score 4):

`-P` (PERL regex) is only supported in `gnu grep` but not on BSD `grep` found on Mac OS.

You can either use `home brew` to install `gnu grep` or else use this equivalent `awk` command:

```sh
awk 'p ~ /foo$/ && /^bar/ {print FILENAME; nextfile}; {p=$0}' *
```

Please note that this eliminates the need to use shell `for` loop.

Comment: Using `ggrep` instead of `grep` after installing GNU grep with `brew install grep` works like `pcregrep -Mq` suggested earlier, thanks!

Comment: This method will work with a native install of MacOS without any extra needed packages

Comment: Using `exit` will cause `awk` to quit after first match.. rest of the files, if any, will not be checked... you can use `nextfile` instead, which is supported by many implementations IIRC

Comment: Very good point @Sundeep, it should be `nextfile`

Answer (score 1):

With [ripgrep](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep)

```sh
rg -lU 'foo\nbar'
```

This will list all filenames containing `foo\nbar` in the current directory. `-U` option allows to match multiple lines. Unlike `grep -z`, whole file isn't read in one-shot, so this is safe to use even for larger input files.

`ripgrep` recursively searches by default. Use `rg -lU --max-depth 1 'foo\nbar'` if you don't want to search sub-directories.

However, note that by default, `rigprep` ignores

- files and directories that match rules specified by ignore files like `.gitignore`
- hidden files and directories
- binary files

You can change that by using:

- `-u` or `--no-ignore`
- `-uu` or `--no-ignore --hidden`
- `-uuu` or `--no-ignore --hidden --binary`

Comment: ++ Wasn't aware of `rg` utility

Comment: @anubhava `ripgrep` is probably the most popular `grep` alternative these days.. it has plenty of speed optimizations (parallel processing, simd, regex optimizations, etc) and is used in software like VSCode, Atom, etc

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are searching for files which have the sequence `foo\nbar`. With GNU awk (`brew install gawk`), you can set the record separator`RS` to this sequence and check if the record matches:

```
gawk 'BEGIN{RS="foo\nbar"}{exit (RT!=RS)}' file
```

This will try to split your files in records which are separated by the record separator `RS`, if so, it will terminate with exit code 0, otherwise with exit code 1. The behaviour is the same as the proposed `grep`

If you just want the files listed, you can do:

```
gawk 'BEGIN{RS="foo\nbar"}(RT==RS){print FILENAME}{nextfile}' *
```

Comment: macos doesn't come with `gnu awk` either